# PHP + POST an HTML form from inside an iFrame and redirect parent

Tags: forms, iframe, redirect

I'm wondering if it's possible to do the following: have an iFrame inside of an HTML page. Inside the iFrame, I have a 'Pay with PayPal' button. When that button is clicked, and thus the HTML form is submitted to PayPal, I want the parent page to redirect to PayPal, rather than just the iFrame. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for `target="_top"`

```
<form action".." target="_top">
</form>
```

Comment: This worked fine, ignore my previous comment, which was wrong

Comment: Just keep in mind: The target attribute is supported in HTML5.

The target attribute was deprecated in HTML 4.01.