# How to apply target value in zend form?

Tags: zend-framework

I have the same requirement like [PHP + POST an HTML form from inside an iFrame and redirect parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535026/php-post-an-html-form-from-inside-an-iframe-and-redirect-parent)

```
<form action".." target="_top">
</form>
```

I am using zend,I have to apply target="_top" in zend form. How can i do this in zend from

Answer (score 2):

I found it by use ,

$this->setAttrib('target', '_top');