# Make login form from iframe

Tags: php, html

I want to make a "login-button"(i can make that), and then I can make a iframe pop up on the screen, but! Then I want to make so the iframe redirect the main-website not the iframe, how can I do that? :)

Thanks!

Comment: ehm? what do you mean? 

What I mean is when i press the mlogin button in the iframe, I want the "main-website" to redirect.

Comment: duplicate question i think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535026/php-post-an-html-form-from-inside-an-iframe-and-redirect-parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it HAVE to be an iframe?  Why not just use a hidden div that becomes visible when you hit your login button?  That way the form is already on the "main page".

Comment: No it doesn't HAVE to be a iframe, i just want something that stand out from the website.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest going with the div - it's a simpler solution IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

in the iframe

```
<form method=".." action=".." id="loginForm" target="_parent" >
...
</form>
```

or by javascript using the `self.parent.location.href` property